# Get DateTime.DayOfWeek for specific culture

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to get [DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) for a specific culture?

Any clue?

Thank you!!!

Comment: How would culture make a difference to the day of the week?  Do you want a different language?

Comment: How is the day of week culture-dependent? Right now it's Monday here, and unless your timezone offset is big enough that's true throughout the world.

Comment: try following DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-EG"))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-EG"))
```

For details, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: This solution uses Tostring() method, but what if I use System.DayOfWeek in this case do you have any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to get the day name of today's `DayOfWeek` in a given culture?

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

("Montag" for germany)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the localized names of days from the [DateTimeFormatInfo.DayNames Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.daynames.aspx):

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
var dateTimeInfo = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat;
var dayNames = dateTimeInfo.DayNames;
var result = dayNames[(int)DayOfWeek.Wednesday];
// result == "Mittwoch"
```

Comment: Depends on what you need. If you need the names of all days, this is better than `ToString("dddd"...`. But if you have a `DateTime` and need the name of the day, `ToString("dddd"...` is better.

Answer (score 1):

string myTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("it-IT"));

the example use italian culture code, for a list of available culture codes check out [this](http://sharpertutorials.com/list-of-culture-codes/)